# JMS in websphere 8.0 - V5 default messaging provider vs WebSphere MQ messaging provider

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, websphere-8

I want to implement a system to add tasks to a queue and then process them later. Since JMS is made for such type of requirements I'd like to use it. I have websphere 8 and I don't know which JMS provider should I use **V5 default messaging provider** or **WebSphere MQ messaging provider**.

My requirement is simple so I plan on having the `Producer` and `Consumer` in same `EAR`.

Also, Is JMS for my requirement is an overkill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Default messaging provider`, the one you didn't mention.

The  `WebSphere MQ provider` is used when you have external WebSphere MQ server, and  `V5 default messaging provider` is used only while migrating from very old WebSphere version.

JMS is usually used when you want to 'queue` some processing, not necessary postpone it in time. As you usually listen(wait) for incoming messages for example using MDB, and process them automatically once they are available. So in your case once you put message in the queue, it would be picked up and processed right away, unless you will have some waiting logic, and get(read) the message from the queue on demand, not automatically.

If you want to schedule tasks, better combination might be database and timer beans rather than JMS. But again, depends on requirements, JMS is also fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JMS configuration or websphere. Do I need to configure a `service bus` before I can use `Default messaging provider`?

Comment: @ares Yes, you need to: create a bus, create a bus destination (via `Service integration` menu), then create connection factory and queue via `Resources > JMS` menu. As starting point check [creating a bus](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tjj0002_.html?lang=en)